# How to find errors raised in Python's documentation?

Tags: python, error-handling

I'm learning Python and don't know where I can find in the docs the potential errors raised by a dictionary or list call.

For instance:

```
d_maxtempm = d_summary[1]['maxtempm']
d_date = parsed_json['history']['date']
```

can raise a IndexOutOfBound or Key error ?

But where is the complete list so i can fully implement my error handling ?

Comment: Read the code or the documentation of the related API module.

Comment: @JohnJohn2 The search on python.org is just plain horrible.

Answer (score 2):

The list of [Built-in Exceptions](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/exceptions.html) can be found in the  Python documentation.

[`list`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range) and [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) are documented, too.

Comment: And while `KeyError` is specified in those docs for `dict`, `IndexError` is not mentioned in those docs for `list`. The answer to this question is *probably* that the Python standard libraries are under-documented, much as that answer would infuriate some people, but certainly the fact is that the aspect of `list` the questioner is interested in is *not* documented at that location.

Comment: @LutzHorn: Don't worry about Joh John2 here; he has taken it upon himself to be the resident downvoting troll. His standards are... unfathomable. If his comments are unconstructive or rude, just flag, and move on.

Comment: sorry but I can't find any "error raised" description in the List doc http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#lists

Answer (score 2):

You can check http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html for all the exceptions.

Dictionary can raise: 
   **KeyError**: http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.KeyError

Lists can raise:
   **IndexError**: http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.IndexError